# Can I put 我觉得 at the end of a sentence instead of at the front?

Tags: grammar

For example: I feel that Chinese is difficult. 我觉得中文很难。

But can I also say: 中文很难我觉得。 ?

Comment: I've encountered Chinese people speaking this way!  In copying them, I've been told it's a grammar error.  I think it's mentally inserted at the start of the sentence, as a correction.

Comment: It's totally ok when speaking. It's better add a comma before `我觉得` when writing: “中文很难，我觉得。”. This is best known as '山东 倒装句', which is very similar to English, such as "Be quiet when you watching movie."

Answer (score 4):

You can. But only in casual conversations, and you need a brief pause before `我觉得` to make the sentence a inversion/倒装句

examples: [山东人逃不过的倒装句，被洗脑了](https://youtu.be/H4TbuKYRHns)

Using the inversions actually makes you sound more native, but don't use it in written forms or exams LOL

Answer (score 2):

First of all, taking a small part of language out of its context is never a good idea. In context, many things become clear.

Second of all: prescriptive grammar takes no account of how people actually speak and is generally a bad idea.

> For human speech is after all a democratic product, the creation, not
> of scholars and grammarians, but of unschooled and unlettered people.
> Scholars and men of education may cultivate and enrich it, and make it
> flower into the beauty of a literary language; but its rarest blooms
> are grafted on a wild stock, and its roots are deep-buried in the
> common soil. [Logan Pearsall Smith, "Words and Idioms," 1925]

I'm afraid I cannot agree with Tang Ho. I see no problem with:

Chinese is hard to learn, I think.

Also, asking around, Chinese friends do not rail at:

中文很难我觉得。

Everyone can understand it.

没有意义的信息是很难记忆的，他认为。
Meaningless information is very hard to remember, he believes.

他认为，没有意义的信息是很难记忆的。
He believes, meaningless information is very hard to remember.

Comment: Everyone can understand it doesn't make 中文很难我觉得 grammatical; What if I say:  都移民了我的家人 instead of 我的家人都移民了? Sure, people can understand what I meant by saying 都移民了我的家人, but they will automatically break the sentence  in their mind and hear it as "都移民了，我的家人"

Answer (score 1):

- 我觉得中文很难 (I think Chinese is hard) is the normal way to construct an SVO sentence in Chinese or English.
- 中文很难我觉得 (Chinese is hard I think) is ungrammatical in Chinese or English.

That answered your question

~

I feel (我觉得) is a transitive verb that requires an object after it

中文很难，我觉得 (Chinese is hard, I think) are two separate phrases. Saying them one after another makes the second phrase sounds like an afterthought. But the biggest problem is the second phrase 我觉得 is an incomplete sentence (a transitive verb without an object)

A complete sentence, in this case, a [topic + comment] sentence should look something like this: "中文很难，我觉得不是每周上三小时课就能学会的" (Chinese is difficult, I don’t think you can learn it by taking three hours of class a week) with 中文很难 as the topic and 我觉得不是每周上三小时课就能学会的 as the comment